# Get dealership under a company

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I have branch index page it contains 2 drop-down menu called company and dealership when i click on company it contains a company i created when click on a company the corresponding dealership should list in the dealership dropdown. i used eloqent straightly into index page i did that because the i can't access the company and dealership in the index page

```
    Index

 @include('theme.header')

    <?php  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;?>


    <div class="page-content-wrapper ">

        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="page-title-box">
                        <div class="btn-group float-right">

                        </div>
                        <h4 class="page-title">Branch Management</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end page title end breadcrumb -->

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="card m-b-30">
                        <div class="card-body">

                            <h4 class="mt-0 header-title">Branch</h4>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <form id="form" method="post" action="{{route('branch.store')}}">
                                {{csrf_field()}}
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Company</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">

                                        <select class="form-control" id="company" name="company">

                                            <option>Select Company</option>
                                            @foreach(\App\Company::all()->where('status','0') as $company)
                                                <option value="{{$company->comp_id}}">{{$company->name}}</option>
                                            @endforeach

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Dealership</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <select class="form-control" id="dealer" name=" dealer">
                                            <option>Select Dealership</option>
                                            @foreach(\App\Dealership::join('companies','comp_id','=','dealerships.comp_id')->where('status','0') as $dealership)

                                                <option value="{{$dealership->dlr_id}}">{{$dealership->name}}</option>
                                            @endforeach

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Branch Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="branch" name="branch" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <div class="page-title-box">
                                            <div class="btn-group float-right">
                                                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_save" data-toggle="modal"
                                                        data-target="#create" type="submit">Save
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </form>


                        </div>
                    </div>


     @include('theme.footer')
```

Comment: What is your question? Have you any error? What is wrong with your code?

Comment: i have no error all need to select a company and list dealership under the selected company @MaKobi

Comment: What is the laravel version that you are using?

Comment: 5.6 @SaiyanPrince

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with Ajax.

1. Create a custom function in controller file. In this case Branch controller, this function contains query builder to retrieve the data
2. Write Ajax, in the index file, the dealership dropdown is hidden default when you select the company the dropdown will show corresponding data.

#### Index File

```
    @include('theme.header')

    <?php  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;?>
    <script language="javascript">


        /*--- Fliter dealership corressponging company---*/

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#dealership_div').hide();

            $('#company').change(function () {
                alert('hello');
                $('#dealership_div').show();
                let id = this.value;
                $.ajax({

                    url: '/filter_dealer',
                    type: "post",
                    data: {option: id},
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#dealer')
                            .find('option')
                            .remove()
                            .end()
                            .append(" <option value=''>--- Select dealership ---</option>")

                        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                            $('#dealer')
                                .append($("<option></option>")
                                    .attr('value', value['dlr_id'])
                                    .text(value['name'])
                                );
                        });


                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Error occurred While Processing");
                    }


                });
            });
        });


    </script>

    <div class="page-content-wrapper ">

        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="page-title-box">
                        <div class="btn-group float-right">

                        </div>
                        <h4 class="page-title">Branch Management</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end page title end breadcrumb -->

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div class="card m-b-30">
                        <div class="card-body">

                            <h4 class="mt-0 header-title">Branch</h4>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <form id="form" method="post" action="{{route('branch.store')}}">
                                {{csrf_field()}}
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Company</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">

                                        <select class="form-control" id="company" name="company">

                                            <option>Select Company</option>
                                            @foreach(\App\Company::all()->where('status','0') as $company)
                                                <option value="{{$company->comp_id}}">{{$company->name}}</option>
                                            @endforeach

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row" id="dealership_div">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Dealership</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <select class="form-control" id="dealer" name=" dealer">

                                            <option></option>

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <label for="example-text-input" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Branch Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="branch" name="branch" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <div class="page-title-box">
                                            <div class="btn-group float-right">
                                                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn_save" data-toggle="modal"
                                                        data-target="#create" type="submit">Save
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </form>


                        </div>
                    </div>
```

#### Branch Controller File With a custom function

```
 public function filter_dealer(Request $request)
    {
        $company_id=$request->input('option');
        $dealership=DB::table('dealerships')->select('dlr_id','name')->where([['comp_id','=',$company_id],['status','=','0']])->get();
        return response()->json($dealership);

    }
```

#### Route File

```
Route::post('filter_dealer', 'BranchController@filter_dealer')->name('filter_dealer');
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing first. You need to change queries.

```
Company::where(‘status’, 0)->get();
```

And next you missed the tailing get() in the next dropdown.
And why are you not using relationships to query?

Comment: it's working fine but it lists all dealerships all i need dealership under the selected company @Muhammed Nauman

Comment: That's where relationships work. define a relationship in between company and dealership and just call `Company::where('comp_id', 1)->with('dealership')->get();`
dealership is your relation name. it will list the company and under it will have all the dealerships associated to it.

Comment: where should i write this in company dropdwon or dealership dropdown @Muhammad Nauman

Comment: Define models like:
`class Company extends Model {
    public function dealerships(){
        return $this->hasMany(Dealership::class, 'comp_id');
    } 
}`

`class Dealership extends Model {
    public function Company(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Company::class, 'comp_id');
    } 
}`

and then in view for second dropdown,
`@foreach(\App\Company::where('status', 0)->with('dealership')->get()->pluck('dealership') as $dealership)
                                            @endforeach`
This is just for the idea once you get along let me know.

Comment: It thorws an error --Property [dlr_id] does not exist on this collection instance @Muhammad Nauman

Answer (score 0):

Like Muhammad Naumann already said you have to use the `get()` method to get the actual data:

```
Company::where(‘status’, 0)->get();
```

On the company select field you could add an event listener like `onChange`. In this listener you run a ajax get request to fetch the dealerships for the selected company.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to dynamically change the contents of dealership dropdown, on the event of changing the company dropdown, you should use javascript, jquery or similar javascript framework, because PHP is a server side scripting language and require page refresh to change the contents of a web page.